# Скрыть адресную строку мобильного браузера

Tags: html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Дано: страница без прокрутки (полноэкранный слайдер)

Условия: должны поддерживаться основные браузеры Android и iOS

Проблема: на малых экранах мобильных устройств, адресная строка занимает многовато места. Да, и слайдер не презентабельно смотрится...

Вопрос: есть ли способ с помощью css или javascript/jQuery скрыть ненависную адресную строку?

---

**UPD 20.09.2023:**
Теперь имеются новые единицы измерения:

**svh** и **svw** (small viewport height/width), наименьший активный размер вьюпорта;

**lvh** и **lvw** (large), наибольший активный размер вьюпорта;

**dvh** и **dvw** (dynamic) - автоматом вписывается во вьюпорт.

Поддержка браузерами: https://caniuse.com/viewport-unit-variants

Answer (score 4):

Думаю нет. Ведь адресная строка это API браузера а повлиять снаружи с помощью перечисленных вами инструментов на интерфейс нельзя.

Comment: Скорее GUI. Но направление верное, этого сделать нельзя. Из JS.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать по другому. Добавить ссылку (в виде приложения) на ваш ресурс https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

Если используете PWA то можно в manifest указать dispalay:fullscreen то при добавление на главный экран Android/iOS приложение будет во весь экран без элементов UI браузера.
Остальные решения это костыль и не будет работать одинаково на всех устройствах

Answer (score -3):

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .your class {display:none}
}
```

Comment: Вопрос не об элементе страницы, а об адресной строке браузера. Чтобы, например, при загрузке главной страница на мобильном устройстве, слайдер развернулся на весь экран и браузерные элементы не мешались под рукой...